# How to detect whether google auth login user is a NewUser or not using firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How to detect the login user is an existing user or a new user using firebase in react native. I have used Google auth to create the authentication but unfortunately I am not getting any field called isNewUser in return promise.

below is my code...

```
async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    // Get the users ID token
    const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }

  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    if (user) {
      firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set({
          user: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photo: user.photoURL,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('User added!');
        });
    }
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }


 useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  });
```

This is the return response I am getting.

```
 {"displayName": "***", "email": "**@gmail.com", "emailVerified": true, "isAnonymous": false, "metadata": {"creationTime": 15960**412290, "lastSignInTime": 15960**65185}, "phoneNumber": null, "photoURL": "**", "providerData": [[Object]], "providerId": "firebase", "uid": "*******"}
```

My problem now is everytime once user successfully authenticate google signin method its adding data's to the firebase data base. Does there any way that I can detect the user is a new user or a existing user??

A help will be great and appreciable :)

Comment: Why don't you just check to see if the per-user document exists before writing it?  If it doesn't exists, then you know it's a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isNewUser` property is in the `UserCredential` object, which is only available right after the call to `signInWithCredential`.

```
const credentialPromise = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
credentialPromise.then((credential) => {
  console.log(credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
})
```

---

You **can** determine whether the user is new from the auth state listener, by comparing the user's creation timestamp to their last sign in:

```
function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
  if (user) {
    if (user.metadata.creationTime <> user.metadata.lastSignInTime) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

---

Also see:

- the documentation for [AdditionalUserInfo](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/additionaluserinfo#isNewUser).
- the documentation for [UserMetadata](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/usermetadata).